# What would be the minimum priveledges required to check/fix crashed MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, security, privileges, mysqlcheck

I'm using the mysqlcheck command for an automated script. I want to give, the user running the script, the  minimum permissions required to be able to successfully run the command with the --all-databases and --repair arguments.

Answer (score 0):

A quick excerpt from the documentation page of [`mysqlcheck`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlcheck.html):

> `mysqlcheck` uses the SQL statements [`CHECK TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html), [`REPAIR TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html), [`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html), and [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html) in a convenient way for the user.

The documentation page of [`CHECK TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html) specifies:

> To check a table, you must have some privilege for it.

The documentation pages of [`REPAIR TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html), [`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html), and [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html) specify:

> This statement requires `SELECT` and `INSERT` privileges for the table.

I think the conclusion is obvious: grant the user only the `SELECT` and `INSERT` [global privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-global-privileges) to be able to successfully run `mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases`.